# Chart.js How to invert (swap) axes?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Taking from inspiration from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608040/how-do-i-invert-an-y-axis-using-chart-js-v2-0-dev/33612465#33612465), I am trying to figure out how to swap the axes of a Line chart in `Chart.js`.

For instance, in Highcharts we have [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-inverted), although it's an area chart.

Is it possible to "swap" the X and Y axis on a line chart?

```
datasets: [
    {
        label: "data1a",
        data: [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3]
    }
]
yAxes: [
   {
     type: "linear",
     display: true,
     position: "left",
    }
]
```

Here's [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmaat/rqnf7qp0/6/) modified from the above link.  I'm basically trying to move it so the graph looks rotated 90 degrees.  I tried changing the y position to 'top' but it still doesn't look correct.

Comment: You want a thing like that (http://jsfiddle.net/dja5xow6/) or i don't really understand ?

Comment: @Onyphlax Yes that looks to be what i want, but for Chart.js not HighCharts

Comment: Well, i don't know sorry :/. Hope you will find a solution

Comment: FYI - I made an example in d3 to explain what I'm talking about - http://jsfiddle.net/jmaat/0nmy5f6u/10/

Comment: Maybe this comment on issue [579](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/579) can help you: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/579#issuecomment-100980002

Comment: Check this example that I made to another question: https://jsfiddle.net/4th6rbcw/3/ 
It's not perfect but it might help!

Answer (score 2):

The proposal by @dralth works fine with version 2.8.0, but for some reason `showLines: true` does not work anymore since version 2.9.0.

It is still possible showing the lines by using the `showLine` property for each dataset.

In case of @dralth's example it works as follows (tested with version 2.9.3):

```
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'My Dataset',
        data: [{x: 3, y: 2}, {x: 5, y: 7}, {x: 9, y: 10}],
        showLine: true
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'bottom',
        },
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          type: 'linear',
        },
      ],
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this in Chart.js 2.8.0:

1. Change data to a list of objects with `x` and `y`. Since the intention is to swap x and y axis, put the "x data" in the y variable and vise verse.
   eg. `[{x: 3, y: 2}, {x: 5, y: 7}, {x: 9, y: 10}]`
2. Set the chart type to 'scatter'
3. Add `showLines: true` to the `options`

The outcome is a line chart where the line can be horizontal, vertical, or even double back on itself. The orientation of the line is defined by which values you put in `x` and which you put in `y`.

Here's an example configuration:

```
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'My Dataset',
        data: [{x: 3, y: 2}, {x: 5, y: 7}, {x: 9, y: 10}],
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    showLines: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'bottom',
        },
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          type: 'linear',
        },
      ],
    }
  }
})
```

If you're using an older version of Chart.js that doesn't have scatter plots, you can use this plugin: http://dima117.github.io/Chart.Scatter/