# Is it possible to display in a chart the axis in reverse, from example the x axis from right to left and the y from left to right? React-chart-js

Tags: charts, chart.js, yaxis, react-chartjs-2, x-axis

I am trying to reverse the axis in a chart,what i want is to have to line of the chart running from left to right and the date.now() from right to left? How can i accomplish that?

I have tried to do x: {
reverse: true
},
y:{

reverse: false
}

Comment: Setting `options.scales.x.reverse` to `true` should work. Include your full code or a simplified version of it (i.e., a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) for us to be able to see where your problem comes from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I invert an y-axis using chart.js (v2.0-dev)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608040/how-do-i-invert-an-y-axis-using-chart-js-v2-0-dev)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can reverse to arrays. In addition, depending on the situation, You can add new items in reverse.

```
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'].reverse(),

          data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40].reverse(),
```